# iOS app user id without permanent device ID

Tags: ios, google-play-services, appstore-approval

I have an application (not a game) and the application store some data in server database for the user, so I need a user id to work with.
Since I cannot have a permanent id in ios devices now, I used the google play games login approach.

The user opens the application and gets redirect to safari where he logs in google and returns to the application and I use the google play games ID for identifying my user.

My binary got rejected because of this, so I can use the iOS game services, but it's not a game, so I'm worried to get rejected again, any one used ios game services just to get an identifier for the user in a non-game app before?

Here is the reject message

> We noticed an issue in your app that contributes to a lower quality user >experience than Apple users expect:
>
> - Upon launching the app, a web page in mobile Safari opens for logging in, then >returns the user to the app. The user should be able to log in without opening >Safari first.

Any other approaches to get an identifier for a user without having to open a browser window at launch?
It will be best if the user does not have to enter a username or password for registration.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common scenario on iOS. Many apps, such as Angry Birds, requires registering with them or using a third party login such as Facebook, or sometimes a Game Center ID, if you want to ensure you won't lose your data upon uninstall of app.

So, it's typical to use the app vendor ID to identify the user server side until the point you have another ID to identify them.

Of course, the vendor ID is reset upon uninstalling/reinstalling the app. The Game Center ID is unique per app, but consistent between installs, so it seems like the Game Center ID is what Apple would prefer you to use.

From [Working with Players in Game Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6):

> **Player Identifier Strings Uniquely Identify Players**
>
> Every player
>   account is uniquely identified by a player identifier string contained
>   within a GKPlayer object. The identifier string is created when the
>   player’s account is first created and never changes, even if other
>   information in the account changes. Thus, player identifiers are the
>   only reliable way to track a particular player. For this reason, the
>   Game Kit API uses player identifiers wherever a specific player needs
>   to be identified. If Game Center needs to identify a specific player
>   in your game, the Game Kit API returns that player’s identifier. Your
>   game uses a player identifier to retrieve information from Game Center
>   about that player.
>
> In addition to using player identifiers in your interactions with Game
>   Center, your game should also use the player identifier whenever it
>   wants to store data locally about a specific player. For example, if
>   your game stores data to track a player’s progress (such as on the
>   device, on your own server, or on iCloud), use player identifiers to
>   distinguish between multiple players playing on the same device. That
>   way, if a different player signs into the device, you can immediately
>   personalize the experience by showing content specific to that player.

Losing progress when uninstalling is standard behavior. Saving progress even after uninstall or sharing progress between devices by registering or logging in is a bonus.

Comment: Great, thanks for the information! I can go with vendor id, but will it pass the review if I use the game center id with a non-game app?

Comment: They probably named Game Center wrong. You can use it outside of "games".